# cakephp validation fails on sql injection

Tags: php, mysql, sql, cakephp, code-injection

i installed a plugin on my firefox browser which is called "SQL Inject Me" and then I tried it against my Cakephp website. I see that it was able to inject few blank accounts (some with password) and some without password. The database is not allowed to accept null values for username, emails etc also I'm not sure how is it able to bypass cakephp validation.

my cakephp validation for username field

```
        'username' => array(
            'username must not be empty' => array(
                'rule' => 'notEmpty',
                'message' => 'username field cannot be empty'
            ),


            'username must be unique' => array(
                'rule' => 'isUnique',
                'message' => 'username is already taken'

            )
            'username must not contain special character' => array(
                'rule' => 'usernameValidation',
                'message' => 'username can only contain numbers, characters, underscores, dashes and Periods. Underscore, dash and Period are only allowed in the middle.'
            )
        )
```

Comment: So what's the question?

Comment: I wouldn't call it failing, as this is expected behavior when you don't require the presence of the fields when doing mass-assigment /-saving. So whitelist them and this will not happen. See [here](http://www.dereuromark.de/2010/09/21/saving-model-data-and-security/).

Comment: @ndm, the question is how do i prevent it. it's obvious that i don't want people to inject blank accounts in my database.

Comment: @mark, no, how can it be an expected behavior? CakePHP validation is set to deny any registration that has empty fields in it. Also I haven't selected "null" for my table fields. So if cakephp validation wasn't failing then cakephp should not execute an 'insert' command in my database and even if it did then the database should throw an error instead of creating a new record.

Comment: Of course, my "question" was just a broad hint that it wouldn't hurt to make your question more question like, currently it doesn't even contain a single question mark and is more like "so yesterday this and that happend to me". As mark said, `notEmpty` doesn't require a field to be set, you need the `require` option to enfore that. Also setting a DB column to `NOT NULL` doesn't prevent from an insert to be successful when the column is not passed at all (try ``INSERT INTO `table` (`id`) VALUES (NULL);``), which is what CakePHP will do when the field is not present in the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Validations were failing because if you remove fields from a form using developers tools like firebug then cakephp validations will not work for those removed fields.

what i did to fix these issues is to use this code right before passing data to save method.

```
            if(!(isset($this->request->data['User']['email']))){
                $this->request->data['User']['email']='';
            }
            if(!(isset($this->request->data['User']['username']))){
                $this->request->data['User']['username']='';
            }
            if(!(isset($this->request->data['User']['password']))){
                $this->request->data['User']['password']='';
            }
            if(!(isset($this->request->data['User']['confirm_password']))){
                $this->request->data['User']['confirm_password']='';
            }
```

If there is a missing field then this code will add that field and assign an empty string to it. Then those fields will be eligible for validation and will eventually fail validation.

Comment: You have good instincts to mess around with your forms with the various tools! Consider enabling security component: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/security-component.html . Also consider setting field in database to "not null" with no default value.

Answer (score 0):

I think your validations has wrong keys. That should be like this..

```
var $validate = array(
    'username' => array(
        'notEmpty' => array(
            'rule' => 'notEmpty',
            'message' => 'username field cannot be empty'
        ),


        'isUnique' => array(
            'rule' => 'isUnique',
            'message' => 'username is already taken'

        )
        'usernameValidation' => array(
            'rule' => 'usernameValidation',
            'message' => 'username can only contain numbers, characters, underscores, dashes and Periods. Underscore, dash and Period are only allowed in the middle.'
        )
    )
)
```

and while saving them you just have to call validate function to go through the validation rules. Below link can help you to how to validate from controller while saving the data.

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation/validating-data-from-the-controller.html

Thanks..!

Answer (score 0):

Add the keys `'required' => true, 'allowEmpty' => false` to your validation arrays.